# ksoap2 android error while connecting to web service

Tags: java, android, web-services, jax-ws, ksoap2

i am trying to connect an android application to a java web service but i get this error:

```
01-30 13:09:58.663    8730-8758/lorenzodaneo.example.com.pmcity W/System.err﹕ SoapFault - faultcode: 'soapenv:Server.userException' faultstring: 'java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 200' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@52f28a7c
01-30 13:09:58.663    8730-8758/lorenzodaneo.example.com.pmcity W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.parseBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:137)
01-30 13:09:58.667    8730-8758/lorenzodaneo.example.com.pmcity W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:140)
01-30 13:09:58.667    8730-8758/lorenzodaneo.example.com.pmcity W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:129)
01-30 13:09:58.667    8730-8758/lorenzodaneo.example.com.pmcity W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.parseResponse(HttpTransportSE.java:301)
01-30 13:09:58.667    8730-8758/lorenzodaneo.example.com.pmcity W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:274)
01-30 13:09:58.667    8730-8758/lorenzodaneo.example.com.pmcity W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:118)
01-30 13:09:58.667    8730-8758/lorenzodaneo.example.com.pmcity W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:113)
01-30 13:09:58.667    8730-8758/lorenzodaneo.example.com.pmcity W/System.err﹕ at lorenzodaneo.example.com.pmcity.ItemLocation$ConnectionWS.doInBackground(ItemLocation.java:99)
01-30 13:09:58.667    8730-8758/lorenzodaneo.example.com.pmcity W/System.err﹕ at lorenzodaneo.example.com.pmcity.ItemLocation$ConnectionWS.doInBackground(ItemLocation.java:78)
01-30 13:09:58.667    8730-8758/lorenzodaneo.example.com.pmcity W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-30 13:09:58.667    8730-8758/lorenzodaneo.example.com.pmcity W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
01-30 13:09:58.667    8730-8758/lorenzodaneo.example.com.pmcity W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
01-30 13:09:58.667    8730-8758/lorenzodaneo.example.com.pmcity W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
01-30 13:09:58.667    8730-8758/lorenzodaneo.example.com.pmcity W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
01-30 13:09:58.667    8730-8758/lorenzodaneo.example.com.pmcity W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I can't understand if it is a web service problem or an android app problem.
I can run web service from eclipse plugin web service explorer and from browser i can see the web.xml page. So i think web service is ok right?
I don't know where to start to solve the problem! Any suggest?

Comment: Imho it is on server. But You know - its on server becouse of data sent from client. Try to see what request is proper, and what is sending Your Android code.

Comment: thank you. I send a String to the server and it have a string parameter. So you think the problem is about the parameter? Sometime i can see on the web service the request has arrived, but the variable returned (String[]) doesn't reached the android client.

Comment: If ws returns a value - i bet it will reach Your client. Try to invesigate what exactly is happen after transport.call. Try to set transport's debug to true, and print its field responseDump or see it in debugger. If there is any xml, post it here. You may also post Your client's code here if You could.

Comment: I think the error is the return type because if i return only a string it work! So now my problem is: how to cast String[] to SoapPrimitive?

Comment: I'll create answer for Your last comment.

Answer (score 0):

SoapPrimitive is for primitive types, so array should be placed in SoapObject. For array, You have to iterate through its elements, and it will be sth like that:

```
SoapObject res=(SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
for(int i=0; i<t.getPropertyCount(); i++){
    String ith_string = res.getProperty(i).toString()
}
```

If it will not help, try to publish here xml reposnse dump.

Comment: I try with that but it won't cast envelope.bodyIn to SoapObject. So i have created another web service that concatenate string by adding a separator and return a string. In android app I only split the string by that separator.